# Minimize number of layouts in custom view Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a pretty simple custom view. However, I need to duplicate this view in my layout a few hundred times which makes the initial drawing very slow (a few seconds). I'm not sure what the best way to approach this is, but I read that having extraneous layouts can slow down the drawing significantly.

When I first designed the custom view, had it extend a `LinearLayout` and then inflated my view's xml into it. But actually, I feel like the `LinearLayout` is a waste. Is there a way to cut it out?

Alternatively, is there a more efficient way to create the same view many times?

---

EDIT

To be clear, the custom views are generated at runtime and the exact number is determined then. Also, these views are embedded in a more complicated layout

---

Below is my Java class:

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

    public TOCNumBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.myview, this);
    }
}
```

And here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="234">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are all 100 views being shown at the same time? If not, such as if they are in a scrollable listview, try using a recyclerview to improve performance. Alternatively, you could put all 100 TextViews in a single layout if they do need to be shown at the same time.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. The custom views are dynamically generated. Only at runtime do I know how many views I need to create. Also, the custom views are in a more complicated layout (all generated at runtime) which has its own scroll view, so a listview isn't a good option. but thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @Bob Android really isn't designed to handle this kind of thing. Consider rethinking your original UI design to show only a few components at a time. Chances are there's a better way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, I agree this is definitely not an ideal design. I'm trying to find alternatives. Do you have an idea about whether or not I need the LinearLayouts?

Comment: @Bob MyView should be extending View since it is a view element, not a view layout. Then put your collection of MyViews into a single layout and inflate that. I'm not sure what kind of widget MyView is based off of but if its a common widget such as checkbox or spinner, you could extend that class instead.